# Predicting Values from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am looking to use a regression model to predict values of which the input is coming from an array.
As seen in the image, i can use the model to predict a value from an input value of 10. I am hoping that this input value can read an array of values and hence produce an array of the predicted values. Is this possible?

```
prediction = lin_reg2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[10]]))

forecast = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Avg WS'])
forecast2000 = forecast.head(2000)
forecast2000.head()

forecast_array = np.array(forecast2000['Avg WS'])
forecast_array.reshape(1,-1)

prediction2 = lin_reg2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[forecast2000]]))
```

I hope this amount of code is sufficient for understanding my problem.

[image]

Comment: Please, no pictures of code! Please take the time to copy-paste your notebook code and output into your question, it will make it easier to answer and more useful to future readers.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Comment: Apologies! I will try to copy and paste everything that is needed in the following comment

Comment: @zerecees i will try to make sense of that now, I'm new to coding so it may take me a while

Comment: @robert, not in a comment please! You can edit the question itself. (Anyway you cannot display code in comments properly... this is by design.) But good luck with the lead you got.

Comment: @alexis I have just posted a new question which includes slightly more code. Apologies again for the confusion as I am new to both coding and StackOverflow so i'm not entirely sure how it works. Im afraid that lead didn't solve my problem

Comment: Oops, that's another no-no... why would you even want to create a second version of your question and not just improve this one? Please read the guidance on how to write good questions, it will help you get useful answers and avoid pushback.

Comment: I think you just need to replace **[10]** in the first line with your array of values.

Comment: Apologies I have been away from work for the week, @NicholasHunter would you be able to give me some further help please?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? What happened?

Comment: An error saying 'Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.' is currently showing. I have tried researching how to fix this but nothing has helped. I have also tried creating a function but have trouble passing an array into the function and so this hasn't helped